# Is there a successor to Darglint?

Tags: open-source, python, software-development

In a lot of my python projects I use the [Darglint](https://github.com/terrencepreilly/darglint) docstring linter as part of the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hooks. But this cool piece of software has been archived since Dec 16, 2022.

Since it is not longer maintained, I think it is a good idea to start looking for an replacement, that is better maintained.

Do you have any recommendations for a nice and maintained python docstring linter that works with google style docstrings and can be used as a pre-commit hook?

---

Edit since I learned something new:

In addition to the above requirements another one emerged:
The docstring linter has to check whether the docstring are in line with the actual code (e.g. number and name of arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adopted `darglint` and renamed my fork to [darglint2](https://github.com/akaihola/darglint2). I'm now maintaining it as a side project. Contributions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

**Ruff**

Python linter, written in Rust, [docs](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/), [repo](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff), MIT license, [`pre-commit` hook](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/usage/)

Feature request to reimplement `darglint`: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/458

[Does Ruff support NumPy- or Google-style docstrings?](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/faq/#does-ruff-support-numpy-or-google-style-docstrings)

> Yes! To enable specific docstring convention, add the following to
> your pyproject.toml:
>
> ```
> [tool.ruff.pydocstyle]
> convention = "google"  # Accepts: "google", "numpy", or "pep257".
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching too and found some tools in that direction, but non of them seems to be a suitable replacement for darglint:

- As mentioned by [Gounou](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/76729/gounou),
  [Ruff](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/) does (among other things) docstring linting. But it goes about it differently: Consider a function with 2 arguments and a docstring which only talks about one argument. Ruff is fine with this, but will make sure that your docstring does not exceed the defined `line-length`. darglint on the other hand is unhappy because you forgot to mention an argument. In my mind ruff and darglint  would add to each other significantly, so it is a good idea to mention Ruff here.
- The same holds true for [flake8-docstrings](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-docstrings), which adds an extension for the [pydocstyle](https://github.com/pycqa/pydocstyle) tool to flake8. It does not check if your docstrings are aligned with your actual code. The problem with `additional_dependencies` (in which flake8-docstrings is used) in the pre-commits is that they stay untouched from `pre-commit autoupdate`, creating manual workload.

These findings are actually in line with what the darglint developer [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/77b1h7/googlestyle_docstring_linter/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to be his goal.

Currently there does not seem to be a suitable replacement for darglint.